# Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with arguments in integrand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a way to evaluate
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t,x) dt
$$

The problem comes from differentiating a recursion relation for the generating function of a branching processes ($f$ is related to a generating function).

Does a form of the chain rule hold, e.g.
$$
f(x,x) + \int_0^x \frac{df}{dx} dt
$$

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes if the function $f(t,x)$ has continuous partial derivatives. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule call [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. @Angelo I think Leibniz integral rule covers this